why the result of 1 & any is any in typescript?
This question came to my mind when I found this code:
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends 1 & T ? Y : N;
I thought 1 is a literal type, and when intersecting it with any, the result retains the specific literal type 1. how am I wrong?

any is an escape hatch from the type system. When you use it, you are basically saying "ignore anything about types here". The intersection does make (mathematical) sense to be 1 - that's how 1 | unknown works. But, again, any isn't really mathematical (well, sort of, but not like all the other types). There is more information in this answer which defines the IfAny type
